# How to retrieve a list of objects from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of `users`, each one of them has a list of objects named `chatRoomList`.[image]

How can i retrieve this list from my DB?
Unfortunately i can't do this:

```
 User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if (user.getObjectId().equals(myId)) {
                List<ActiveChatRoom> list = user.getActiveChatRooms();

                }
```

I tried to iterate through the result

```
 for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Log.e(TAG, "User val " + child.getValue().toString());

                    }
```

But i don't know what to do with the value i get:

```
User val {-KZGY1PWEFgMoHIap8Ew={receiversName=Test2, chatRoomId=-KZGY1KxX6zeUr3zAVNL, receiversPic=www.url.com}, -KZGXztjZ73GhCaabrBg={receiversName=Test, chatRoomId=-KZGXzp5jp4br0AL6edD, receiversPic=www.url.com}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `User` class needs to include following (assuming you have `ChatRoom` java class for example):

`Map<String,ChatRoom> chatRoomList;`

Comment: Thanks! So i must use `Map` because of the Firebase structure?

Comment: @GidiSprintzin yes, exactly

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseReference frndMuteRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users/" + getFirebaseUser().getUid().trim() + "/friendlists");
        Query queryRef = frndMuteRef.orderByChild(MUTE).equalTo(YES);
        queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String,MuteModel>> t=  new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String,MuteModel>>() { };

                HashMap<String,MuteModel> hashMap= (HashMap<String,MuteModel>)dataSnapshot.getValue(t);

                if(hashMap!=null) {
                   muteModelList = new ArrayList<MuteModel>(hashMap.values());
                    for (MuteModel muteModel: muteModelList){
                        muteModel.setIsgroup(NO);
                    }

                }else{
                   muteModelList = new ArrayList<MuteModel>();


                }



            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Incase of MuteModel just pass your chat model object.Use the reference like `yourrootreference +"/chatRoomList"`.I think this will do the work